# 13 ways in which the Torah is trampled

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, torah-study, rabbis

I've found a [reference in a book](https://ibb.co/k3CRF5y) to a medieval Italian document which refers to "the 13 ways in which the Torah is trampled and profaned". Can anyone tell me more about these 13 ways?

Comment: It’s a play on words. It’s just saying that the offending ‘rabbi’ took liberties with the words of the Torah

Comment: @JoelK What's the significance of teh number 13 in the play on words?

Comment: @Zarka It comes from the 13 hermeneutical ways of the Torah. See for example, [Sanhedrin 86a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sanhedrin.86a.16?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi). As stated in the footnote, it's a play on the Hebrew, which is Nidreshet/Nidreset - נדרשת/נדרסת.

Comment: BTW, what book is the footnote from?

Comment: I found the referred essay on JSTOR. It was included in a letter that was written during a harsh disagreement between Rabbi Eliezer Ashkenazi and Rabbi Avraham Menachem Rapaporto. In the letter, Rabbi Ashkenazi wrote: "ועתה נתגלגלו דברי פי מגידי אמת וקים לי בגוויהו מפיהם ומפי כתבם, שהאיש הזה נוסף על היותו בלתי ראוי...אף גם זאת אני שמעתי מתנהג בי"ג מידות שהתורה נדרס"ת בהם, ולכן אמרתי כדי לתקן המעוות אסורה נא ואראה טרם אמות...וכאשר הגיע אלי וראיתי על ככה, אני אומר...לא רב ולא חבר יתקרי."

Comment: (pg. [63](https://www.jstor.org/stable/23494042?read-now=1&refreqid=excelsior%3A59e60adbfe518d244e08f5a90514d557&seq=63#page_scan_tab_contents))